# Linq to sql query not returning correct items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Hi i am having an issue with a query to my db. I have looked through the questions on here and have not found anything similar although my title is similar to some other questions. The site i am working on can create collection requests and then view them in a table to manage existing requests. The first query i used works and returns the correct requests. The original query can be seen below.

```
var query = context.LogisticsRequests.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Type == types.Collection.ToString());
```

A new option to delete a request has been added however this is just a new column in the db called isDeleted, this way the request is removed from the table but there is still an archived copy. So in order to filter out deleted requests i updated the query as seen below.

```
var query = context.LogisticsRequests.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Type == types.Collection.ToString() && x.isDeleted != true);
```

After changing the query no results are returned and i cant understand why, only one request is set to deleted and most of the others will have a null value so they should still be returned since there not equal to true. Ive included some screenshots below showing the query result and the query sent to the database. Thank you for any help or suggestions.

[image]

The query sent to the db:

```
    {SELECT [t0].[LogisticsRequestId], [t0].[CreatedOn], [t0].[ModifiedOn], [t0].[CreatedById], [t0].[ModifiedById], [t0].[Type], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[SupplierReference], [t0].[DateRequested], [t0].[CourierType], [t0].[ClientName], [t0].[Laboratory], [t0].[LaboratoryId], [t0].[Reference], [t0].[SpecialInstructions], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactNo], [t0].[ContactEmail], [t0].[CollectionAddress], [t0].[UserLogisticsAddressId], [t0].[ClientLogisticsAddressId], [t0].[SiteName], [t0].[CollectionInstructions], [t0].[RequestDetails], [t0].[EstimatedDeliveryDate], [t0].[Status], [t0].[Comment], [t0].[NumberCoolBoxes], [t0].[CollectionFrom], [t0].[CollectionTo], [t0].[CallBefore], [t0].[PleaseCall], [t0].[isDeleted]
FROM [dbo].[LogisticsRequest] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Type] = @p0) AND (NOT ([t0].[isDeleted] = 1))
}
```

Again thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't like this && x.isDeleted != true ) 
It's better to write && !x.Deleted

Comment: For all the records that don't have the flag 'IsDeleted' , are they all 0 or are they null or a mix?

Comment: True but its a nullable type, bool? so id have to cast to bool for that to work, which still returns the same result and if i do a cast it would throw an exception since a lot of the values are null at least i think thats how it works. I do agree though if it was different i would use !x.isDeleted :).

Comment: @sr28 since its a new column the older records will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in `IsDelete` column there must be value. For all record it must be either `true` or `false`. Make sure you are not storing `null` in `IsDelete`  column. If it's null then you have to set `true` or `false`.

Change your query to

```
var query = context.LogisticsRequests.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Type == types.Collection.ToString() && !(x.isDeleted == null ? false : x.IsDeleted));
```

Comment: What would i do about existing requests though i dont want to go through the db and have to change each value. if i change the table to not allow null values will the value default to 0? Thank you.

Comment: That did the trick thank you, i think at a later point i will go back and change the db so its either true or false but for now i have to allow the null value, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the new column "isDeleted" is filled for all rows. If the column is newly created, it's possible that it contains `null`, so the SQL query will fail. Fill the table with `true` and `false`.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you should rather use "!isDeleted".

Answer (score 0):

Curious about this

```
Where(x => x.Type == types.Collection.ToString()
```

is types a collection of types? Then it should read

```
 types.Collection.Contains(x.Type)
```

Like so

```
Where(x => types.Collection.Contains(x.Type) && !x.isDeleted)
```